# replace/move value with certain string [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

I got a dirty data set like this, for example, if email is filled in `phone` column, I need to move the email to `email` column and leave the `phone` column blank, if email and phone are filled in the wrong place like A03, I need to swap them to the right column.

```
ID             Phone            Email
A01            111111           abc@mail.com
A02            bcd@mail.com     NaN
A03            def@mail.com     222222222
```

currently, I can remove all cells in `phone` column with email address, but I don't know how to compare two column and swap them.

```
eduDup['phone'] = eduDup.phone.str.replace(r'(^.*@.*$)', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa sport')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sorted` with `re.findall`:

```
df = df.fillna('')
df[['Phone', 'Email']] = [sorted(t, key=lambda x:re.findall(r'(^.*@.*$)', x)) 
                          for t in df[['Phone', 'Email']].values]
```

Output:

```
    ID      Phone         Email
0  A01     111111  abc@mail.com
1  A02             bcd@mail.com
2  A03  222222222  def@mail.com
```

Insight:

`for t in df[['Phone', 'Email']].values`: iterates `Phone` and `Email` columns row by row:

```
[('111111', 'abc@mail.com'), 
 ('bcd@mail.com', ''),  
 ('def@mail.com', '222222222')]
```

`sorted(t, key=lambda x:re.findall(r'(^.*@.*$)', x))` now then sorts for each tuple `t`, check if element of tuple is an email. See what happens without `sorted` and just apply `lambda`:

```
f = lambda x:re.findall(r'(^.*@.*$)', x)
[[f(i) for i in t] for t in df[['Phone', 'Email']].values]
# Output
[[[], ['abc@mail.com']], 
 [['bcd@mail.com'], []], 
 [['def@mail.com'], []]]
```

Now `sorted` with `key=f` will *sort* by checking element using `f`. After applying key, empty list will come to the front (because empty list `[]` evaluates as `False` whereas `[...]` is `True`: check with `[] < [1]`).

```
[sorted(t, key=f) for t in df[['Phone', 'Email']].values]
```

which results:

```
[['111111', 'abc@mail.com'],
 ['', 'bcd@mail.com'],
 ['222222222', 'def@mail.com']]
```

And there's the desired output!

Comment: Thanks, That looks great!  I'm still a little bit confused how the `sorted` with `for loop` will help organise the data in the right place

Comment: It's taking `(Phone, Email)` pair and reorder by checking if any of them is an email-like format, and do this row by row. Let me edit to give some insights.